# Async WCF service call blocking UI thread

Tags: wcf, asynchronous

We are having trouble with a background call from our WPF application.  Seemingly, on older computers (we have seen it most often on Windows 7 machines with 2GB of RAM or so) our web service call **blocks the UI** until it completes.  For one call in particular, that is a huge problem because it can take five minutes to complete.  Newer computers seem to handle it fine.

We don't care about the amount of time the call takes; we only care about it not blocking the UI.  I do not see anything we are doing wrong off-hand.

Are we doing something wrong, or is it something with Windows 7 on 2GB of RAM?  Is theere any way to work around it on such a machine?

Do we have to go to the level of writing a custom `TaskScheduler` to make sure the UI thread does not get used?  I sure hope not.

Any input at all is greatly appreciated.  Thanks in advance.  See code samples below.

`DownloadBusinessEntityAsync` is the method our application calls:

```
    #region DownloadBusinessEntity
    public async Task<BusinessEntity> DownloadBusinessEntityAsync(string businessEnityId)
    {
        BusinessEntity ret = new BusinessEntity();

        var client = new DownloadContext();

        try
        {
            Func<AsyncCallback, object, IAsyncResult> begin = (callback, state) => client.BeginDownloadBusinessEntity(businessEnityId, callback, state);
            Func<IAsyncResult, BusinessEntity> end = client.EndDownloadBusinessEntity;

            // ***THIS TAKES FIVE MINUTES TO FINISH***
            ret = await Task<BusinessEntity>.Factory.FromAsync(begin, end, null);

            if (client.State != CommunicationState.Faulted)
                client.Close();
            else
                client.Abort();
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            client.Abort();
        }

        return ret;
    }
    #endregion
```

`DownloadContext` is the WCF client:

```
public partial class DownloadContext : ClientBase<IDownloadService>, IDownloadService, IDownloadContext, IDisposable
{
    public BusinessEntity DownloadBusinessEntity(string agencyId, IEnumerable<int> activeHashCodes)
    {
        return base.Channel.DownloadBusinessEntity(agencyId, activeHashCodes);
    }

    public IAsyncResult BeginDownloadBusinessEntity(string agencyId, IEnumerable<int> activeHashCodes, AsyncCallback callback, object asyncState)
    {
        return base.Channel.BeginDownloadBusinessEntity(agencyId, activeHashCodes, callback, asyncState);
    }

    public BusinessEntity EndDownloadBusinessEntity(IAsyncResult result)
    {
        return base.Channel.EndDownloadBusinessEntity(result);
    }
}
```

`IDownloadService` is the contract the WCF client implements.

```
[ServiceContract(Namespace = "http://namespace.com/services/v1")]
public partial interface IDownloadService
{
    [OperationContract(ProtectionLevel=ProtectionLevel.Sign, Action="http://namespace.com/services/v1/IDownloadService/DownloadBusinessEntity", ReplyAction="http://namespace.com/services/v1/IDownloadService/DownloadBusinessEntityResponse")]
    BusinessEntity DownloadBusinessEntity(string agencyId, IEnumerable<int> activeHashCodes);

    [OperationContract(AsyncPattern=true, ProtectionLevel=ProtectionLevel.Sign, Action="http://namespace.com/services/v1/IDownloadService/DownloadBusinessEntity", ReplyAction="http://namespace.com/services/v1/IDownloadService/DownloadBusinessEntityResponse")]
    IAsyncResult BeginDownloadBusinessEntity(string agencyId, IEnumerable<int> activeHashCodes, AsyncCallback callback, object asyncState);

    BusinessEntity EndDownloadBusinessEntity(IAsyncResult result);
```

}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you simply don't want to block the UI then move that work to a background thread. All that async WCF stuff is not needed to achieve your goal. Something like:

```
await Task.Run(() => DownloadBusinessEntityAsync(...));
```

And you can make `DownloadBusinessEntityAsync` sync if you like.

Comment: Actually, that is what we had before, and I believe it had the same problem. We have been working on this issue a long time so perhaps something has changed.  @Stephen Cleary's answer sounds very much like what we are seeing.

Comment: This will never exhibit any blocking. DNS resolution will happen on the thread-pool. Replace the body of your method with Thread.Sleep(1000000) and see for yourself.

Comment: Would putting a Task.Run inside DownloadBusinessEntityAsync be able to accomplish the same thing (DNS in thread pool)?  That async call is part of our "async layer" which separates the application from the actual call.  If possible, I'd like to avoid having the application do the Task.Run.  Thanks again for your help!

Comment: As long as you place whatever was blocking before on the thread pool the blocking will not affect the UI thread. So yes, that would work. Just wrap everything inside that method or use a separate wrapper method.

Comment: From what I can see, this seems to be working.  There seems to be something else going on, but it seems to be before the WCF call.  I'll post if not.  Thanks again!

Answer (score 2):

There is a known problem with Microsoft's implementation of client-side HTTP connections (`HttpWebRequest` and friends): they do some work synchronously, including DNS resolution and (I believe) proxy detection. This work is always done synchronously even for an asynchronous request, and it may take some time depending on your network configuration.

I'm not sure if the WCF clients share this bug, but it's likely. The best workaround is to wrap it in a `Task.Run` as per [usr's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29715408/263693).

Comment: Thanks for your response.  Does the DNS resolution take five minutes though?  Or do you mean that everything after the DNS resolution will be synchronous as well?  Also, is that known problem present in even the most recent versions of Windows? As I wrote to @usr, I'll try reverting to Task.Run, but I believe that is what we had before.  Could using a different method for client-side HTTP connections also get around the problem?

Comment: This is a problem in the .NET framework, regardless of Windows version. DNS (and proxy) resolution do not *normally* take that long unless your network is misconfigured. The actual WCF call is performed asynchronously. AFAIK, all .NET-based HTTP clients have this issue.