# WPF using MVVM with WCF in a async await pattern

Tags: c#, wpf, wcf, mvvm, async-await

I'm building a WPF app that uses MVVM as pattern together with a WCF backend.
My UI must always be responsive and for some controls the data can be up to 10 seconds to load.

Following code works well and is inside my viewmodel where ConfigurationsForInterface is an Observable type that is bound to my control:

```
ConfigurationsForInterface = new ObservableCollection<string>() { "Loading..." };      
ConfigurationsForInterface = await GetConfigurationInterfaceXAsync();
```

**Method that works fine:**

```
      public async Task<ObservableCollection<string>> GetConfigurationHL7Server5Async()
        {
            ObservableCollection<string> result;

            using (var localClient = new ManagerListenerClient(Globals.ChannelBinding, Globals.EndpointAddress))
            {               
                result = await  localClient.GetConfigurationsAsync("interfacex");
            }

            return result;
        }
```

**Method that freezes my UI** as I reuse the service client already opened in other areas of the app as I set a context for the service (user):

> ```
>   public async Task<ObservableCollection<string>> GetConfigurationHL7Server5Async()
>     {
>         ObservableCollection<string> result;
>
>         result = await Globals.Client.GetConfigurationsAsync("interfacex"); 
>
>         return result;
>     }
> ```

It seems like the WCF client is somehow bound to my UI thread and causes my UI to freeze until the data is loaded. I can see from my debugging that it does not wait in the method itself.

Can someone help me out why I cant reuse my WCF client object that is used elsewhere and not always in a async context like just sync calling the viewmodel

Comment: Can you show how this method are used?

Comment: Just a tip:  never use a WCF client in a global context.  Its just asking for a memory leak from connections not closing properly.

Comment: oh and also, WCF clients aren't thread safe, so making multiple calls with the same client at the same time will probably throw you for a loop

Comment: Hi Mike, the wcf service is session based. So when opening the client I set a state for the session on the server (like when the user authenticates the result will vary based on the priv. level of the user by example). This state is kept for this session the whole time the client is open.This works just fine. If I would follow your adivice this means for every async call I would need to set my state on the session to set iusers priv level of what the service returns... something I want to avoid at all costs.

Comment: Have you tried 
`result = await Globals.Client.GetConfigurationsAsync("interfacex").ConfigureAwait(false)` ?

Comment: @CédericMissinne How old is your proxy? I'd try regenerating it.

Comment: Proxy is not old... and I tried Configur‌​eAwait(false) also with no luck.

Comment: Try using Task.Factory.StartNew and explicitly set the TaskScheduler. It should don't capture the current Context

Comment: Same result  Maybe need to think for another approach but can't seem to understand why this is not working.

Comment: Nowhere in your example code are you showing how the *UI* is involved. There is something very fishy about what you are doing with `ConfigurationsForInterface `...where is this code being run? You must be using INPC somewhere. Ugh this question really is a mess with no thought to let us help you.

Comment: @Schneider I clearly Indicate this is in a MVVM pattern so ObservableCollection<string> ConfigurationsForInterface  is a property in the viewmodel which get loaded by a method in the viewmodel. This would be databound to the itemsource of a ComboBox etc.

Comment: I wonder if this has something to do with Stephen Cleary's answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/29715989/3063835 with regards to a bug in http connections in the .net framework. I know you said you tried Task.Factory.StartNew, but I wasn't sure at what level you put that in. What if you wrap the entire client call in a new task?

Comment: @CédericMissinne "MVVM pattern" tells me nothing. Setting `ConfigurationsForInterface` TWICE is very unorthodox. Where is this happening? In the ctor? From a button click? What? You need to show how and where this interacts with the UI thread. What calls this "load" method?

Comment: new Task(async () => ConfigurationsForInterface = await GetConfigurationInterfaceXAsync()).Start();

Comment: I believe your first lines are running synchronously and getting jammed up at: ConfigurationsForInterface = await GetConfigurationInterfaceXAsync();

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to @Rowbear I pinpointed the real issue.

I changed my binding from WsHttpBinding to NetTCPBinding and then everything runs nicely async. For my app I can easily use NetTCPBinding.

It seems that something is still going sync. in the WsHttpBinding implementation.

Thanks! for the advice.